# Write stdout to screen and file

Tags: powershell, stdout, io-redirection

When running a powershell script from the powershell console, I can redirect the output to a file like this:

```
powershell script.ps1 > file.txt
```

However, I need to redirect the output to a file AND still print it to the screen. How can I do this?

Comment: Look at the Tee-Object cmdlet and see if that gets you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [transcript](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849687.aspx).  You can do it one of two ways, the easiest is probably including these lines in your script:

In "Script.ps1"

```
Start-Transcript "C:\file.txt"
# the rest of your script
Stop-Transcript
```

The second way would be to call your script like so:

```
Start-Transcript "C:\file.txt"
.\Script.ps1
Stop-Transcript
```

Keep in mind that if you try to start a transcript, without the previous transcript not stopped, it will throw an error.  So in your script, prior to the Start-Transcript command, maybe do this just to ensure the transcript isn't still running:

```
try{
Stop-Transcript
}catch{}
Start-Transcript "C:\file.txt"
# the rest of your script
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: 1) I would rather have just a one-liner 2) This transcribes everything, not just stdout

Comment: Warning to future dwellers: this doesn't work with Python 3, and presumably with more software.